# WML and WAP development environment for school purpose

Tags: mobile, ide, emulation, wap, wml

I am studying WML and WAP at semester 5 in BscIT and i had hard time finding the `nokia wap toolkit` as used in my books.When i finally got a copy from a friend , it never loaded the `jvm` even though beside `java 1.6`  that was previouly installed i installed `jre 1.4` .Besides i have a dual booting windows7/Ubuntu12.04. i clearly prefer working from Ubuntu. Is there any alternatives. Like IDE, `eclipse`, `netbeans`, `intellij` ? what I've seen  so far are `Android sdk,java MIDP projects` from these IDEs but not some sort of wml project.

Please point me to the right direction. thank you

Comment: Strange to see WML and WAP at Uni still...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the Openwave SDK, which has been helpfully archived [here](http://blog.wapreview.com/3733/). Sadly, just like the Nokia WAP Toolkit it is no longer available or supported by the manufacturer.

Obviously it isn't going to match the examples in your books, but it should give you a simple environment in which to run and test WAP applications. Note this is Windows only, and pre-dates Windows 7; hopefully it will run.

Answer (score 0):

do code in a document file and give .wml extension. After that to run this code just add a [add-ons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/wmlbrowser/) to your firefox. It's great to work with these.

Thanks.